# Unblock an automated blocked user

Tags: 7, users, security

I used [Login Security](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_security) module to block users after some login failures. It works fine however I need to unblock such users after certain time like after 1 hour/day. How would I do that as it has configurations to *delete attempt* from database but user isn't unblocked and it has to be *active* manually.

Please see below attached screen shot of module configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just developed a small module named as [Auto Unblock Users](https://www.drupal.org/project/auu) to unblock users.

This will only work if the user is blocked by [Login Security](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_security) module.

Answer (score -1):

What about unblocking the blocked user after an hour using Rules module?

Edited:

Use Rules module.

Create custom event for your particular module event (for example, "User Blocked after login failure"

Unblock users after one hour.

Comment: Bulk of users might be blocked earlier by site admin manually. I need to unblock those users who has 0 attempts in database only or blocked by using this module.
As you suggested by using Rules, every blocked user will be unblock who even never tried to logged in once.